# PHP: Run query based on the URL?

Tags: php, url, search, dns

Hopefully I can explain this properly...

I have a search engine script that runs off PHP and uses API's from various places. I would like to be able to generate query results ($q) based on the URL.

e.g. If a user goes to domain.com/stackoverflow I would like the site to automatically generate a query that runs a search for "stackoverflow". i.e. $q = stackoverflow.

I suppose this is the opposite of the header function in PHP, where instead of putting information into the URL bar I want to take information out.

I realise there may be some editing to .htaccess to make this work, but is it possible? It would also mean being able to handle conflicts with whatever might already sit on the site, e.g. I would need to define that domain.com/login is reserved and to not run a query search on that, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is done through the `$_GET` array.

Imagine this is your url: `http://www.website.com/?foo=bar` then `$_GET['foo']` will be `bar`.

If you want to do something like `domain.com/stackoverflow` you will need to use htaccess to rewrite that url to something like `domain.com/?domain=stackoverflow` and then you can access it through `$_GET['domain']`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, you could use the function parse_url(). [Here you have the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing what you want.

1. You should use [`.htaccess` to `ModRewrite`](http://www.blogstorm.co.uk/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/) it in a way so that `example.com/?q=whatver` will become `example.com/whatever`, and then use PHP's [`$_GET` superglobal](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php). to get the information normally.
2. You could use PHP's [`parse_url()` function](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), get the **path** and use it (`$parsed_url['path']`).

Good luck :)